# Using ajax to fetch from script having return value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery and ajax. Is it possible to use ajax in a php script which is returning value?

```
$.ajax({
         url:'ajax.php',
         method:'post',
         dataType:'json',
         success:function(response) {
            alert(response);
         }
      });
```

In my php script

```
<?php
  $sum = 1+5;
  return $sum; //usually echo(json_encode(array("$sum"))); is used
?>
```

Is this even possible? 
P.S I am using `return` because in the main script this function is called from another function. But for ajax i need only this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` only means something in context of the PHP script, and would need to have something else calling that and `echo`ing the results. The AJAX request can only handle things that are actually sent to it, so in the context of a result only being `return`ed, and not `echo`ed, the AJAX request doesn't see anything. As a very general, non-encompassing way to check, if you can't see it when you navigate to it in a browser window, the AJAX request won't either.

If you're wanting to not wrap this code within the main function, you'll likely have to write an additional function that simply `echo`s it.